# javascript for loop unexpected results

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dictionary, partial, higher-order-functions

I am using a function called partial which creates another function based on the arguments you give it. However for some reason i am getting unexpected results if inside the function i call a for loop like this without using var.  `for(i=1; i<knownArgs.length; i++)` however when i call the for loop with using var as so `for (var i = 1; i < knownArgs.length; i++)` i get the result i expected. Here are the functions i am using and the result i expect.

```
var op = {
    "+": function(a, b){return a+b;},
    "==": function(a, b){return a == b;},
    "===":function(a, b){return a === b;},
    "!":function(a){return !a;}
};

function map(func, array){
    var result = [];
    forEach(array, function(element){
        result.push(func(element));
    });
    return result;
}
function forEach(array, action){
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        action(array[i]);
    }
}


function partial(func) {
  var knownArgs = arguments;
  return function() {
    var realArgs = [];
    for(i=1; i<knownArgs.length; i++){
      realArgs.push(knownArgs[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
      realArgs.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return func.apply(null, realArgs);
  };
}


console.log(map(partial(op["+"], 1), [0,2,4,6,8,10]));
```

When i make the call at the end i am expecting an array [1,3,5,7,9,11] and i do get that when inside the two for loops inside the partial() function have var i = #. However i have never used a var there before and can someone explain to me why when i do not use it i get an infinite loop that returns an array of 3s and 4s.

Comment: If you don't declare `i` with `var`, then it's **global** (and an error in JavaScript "strict" mode).

Comment: but even if its global once the first loop finishes i is set back to 0 and there should be no reason for any errors right ?

Comment: Well it works unless one function using "i" in a loop calls *another* function that uses the same variable.